# Does anybody know what $S^1$ is in the following formula?

Tags: calculus

[image]

Where it says $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$, I do not understand what $S^1$ is.

Any idea?

Comment: The unit circle (center the origin, radius $1$) is denoted by $S^1$.

Comment: $S^1$ is the 1 dimensional sphere, aka the unit circle...

Comment: Look up $n$-sphere

Comment: so does it say the cross product of the unit 1-sphere and 2 dimension coordinates? R×S1 if so how do i understand that?

Comment: Not the cross product, the cartesian product. Elements are of the form (x,y) where x $\in \mathbb{R}$ and y $\in S^1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set
$$
    S^n = \left\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 = 1\right\}
$$
is called the *unit $n$-sphere*.  The unit 2-sphere is what's normally called “the” unit sphere in three-dimensional space.  The unit 1-sphere $S^1$ is another name for the unit circle in the plane.  The notation and the equation generalizes to any number of dimensions though.

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, the cartesian product $A\times B$ is set of all pairs
$$
    A \times B = \left\{(a,b)\mid a\in A,\ b\in B\right\}
$$
So in your case, $\mathbb{R} \times S^1$ is the set of all pairs $(t,\theta)$, where $t$ is a real number and $\theta$ is an angle.  This paragraph is saying that lines in the plane can be specified (though not uniquely) by two quantities: the minimum distance $t$ from the line to the origin, and the angle $\theta$ normal to the line.

Comment: oh thank u so much!!!

Comment: so does it say the cross product of the unit 1-sphere and 2 dimension coordinates?  R×S1 if so how do i understand that?

Comment: @gulya: see edits.

Comment: again thank  u for the explanation))))))))